# qt moc error:usr/include/c++/10/bits/fs_fwd.:39: Parse error at "std"

Tags: qt, moc

my configuration is:

```
ubuntu 21.04
gcc 11
qt 5.15.2
```

and error message like this:

```
AutoMoc subprocess error
------------------------
The moc process failed to compile
  "SRC:/src/Layers/ViewLayer/Process/NearFieldProcessUtil.h"
into
  "SRC:/build/MTESS_autogen/MLM4FWGUYC/moc_NearFieldProcessUtil.cpp"

Command
-------
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/moc -DJSON_DIAGNOSTICS=0 -DJSON_USE_IMPLICIT_CONVERSIONS=1 "-DvtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT_INCLUDE=\"/home/alex/workspace/mtess/MTESS/build/CMakeFiles/vtkModuleAutoInit_be7301261a49b13d6a9b1d9e110eacd8.h\"" -I/home/alex/workspace/mtess/MTESS/src -I/home/alex/workspace/mtess/MTESS/vendor/ProjectStructure -I/home/alex/workspace/mtess/MTESS/vendor/imgui -I/home/alex/workspace/mtess/MTESS/vendor/imgui/imgui -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/local/qwt-6.2.0/include -I/usr/local/include/opencascade -I/lib -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/vtk-9.0 -I/usr/include/c++/10 -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/c++/11 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11 -I/usr/include/c++/11/backward -I/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0/include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --include /home/alex/workspace/mtess/MTESS/build/MTESS_autogen/moc_predefs.h --output-dep-file -o /home/alex/workspace/mtess/MTESS/build/MTESS_autogen/MLM4FWGUYC/moc_NearFieldProcessUtil.cpp /home/alex/workspace/mtess/MTESS/src/Layers/ViewLayer/Process/NearFieldProcessUtil.h

Output
------
usr/include/c++/10/bits/fs_fwd.:39: Parse error at "std"
```

The same codebase compiled successfully in windows with **qmake**,and I am converting compilaltion approch to **cmake**,and it shouldn't be a code problem,but a cmake configuration or tool chain compatibility problem.My questions are:

1. How to let cmake use the only one includes of specific compiler?

   As you can see,it seems like 3 includes of gcc-10,gcc-11,clang-14 are all being used.I have tried to uninstalled gcc-10 but clang-14 depends on it,and I have used **update-alternatives** to specify gcc,g++,clang and clang++.
2. How to debug this kind of standard library moc parsing problem?

   I have met the similar  MOC parsing problem before,not on usr/include/c++/10/bits/fs_fwd.:39,but another gcc header file,after some uninstalling/installing,that problem gone,but actually I don't know how is gone.This type of problem maybe kind of general,any method to troubleshoot them?

Answer (score 6):

I hit this issue too. This seems to be an open [bug in `moc`](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-73263) that is triggered when the `filesystem` header is included before any Qt headers.

Moving `#include <filesystem>` below `#include <QApplication>` fixed the problem for me.